# Change the name of the column to be taken from the database

Tags: php, laravel

How can I change the questioned to the database which is automatically generated.I have in blade template this

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->friends()->get()}}
```

and it generates

```
Unknown column 'friends.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `friends` where `friends`.`user_id` = 1 and `friends`.`user_id` is not null
```

because my column name is `user_id1` insted `user_id`.

and I do not know why the query to the database takes the `user_id` value instead of `user_id1`. How can I change it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the custom foreign key in the `friends` relationship:

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class, 'user_id1');
}
```